# Devise - One Model and Multiple Different Registration Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to use Devise for authentication in rails 3.1.

I've created a pricing table on a static "signup" page that has three options. Level A, B and C.

I want to either pass the signup selection to devise as a parameter, or create separate views for the different options, but use the same User model.

I'm not really sure which way to go, or how to customize devise in a way to handle this.

Any input would be greatly appreciated! We're rails newbies.

Answer (score 2):

1) put an attribute "subscription_level" into your user model

2) create views which determine what the value of  `current_user.subscription_level`  is, 
   and which display different content depending on it's value...

Comment: Tile , i think you didn't noticed the question . it's saying showing the views at the time of registration - and you're mentioning `current_user`

Comment: thanks Tilo, your solution has directed me to the right way: just passing a variable to the controller action and returning it to the new view to adapt it to the layout I want... Of course there is no current_user yet but it is not necessary to have it yet.